# django-pytest: AssertionError

Tags: python, django, pytest-django

Im new to Django testing and Iam passing a context inside my views but my test case fails.when I query `Question.objects.all()` in django shell I get one value

My views

```
def home(request):
    list = Question.objects.all()
    context = {'list': list}
    return render(request,'index.html',context)
```

test.py

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
    class TestUsers:

        def test_user(self,client):
            response = client.get("/test", follow=True)
            assert len(response.context['list'])==1
```

Though Im sending context test fails, What could be possible change to make my test case pass
[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe there're no questions in the test database? Do you use fixtures?

Comment: How should I specify a test DB..right now Im having only one DB.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure, that you have data in your test DB first. You can do it with debugger, just insert [pytest.set_trace()](https://pytest.org/latest/usage.html#setting-a-breakpoint-aka-set-trace) in your code and then invoke your query `Question.objects.all()` by hand. Also, check [DATABASES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#databases) setting in your test configuration.